# jQuery - Following div on Scroll that stops at specified top or bottom margin

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3ncyxnzt/

It currently works well as far as always stopping at a specified margin from the top of the page, but I'd like to make it also stop at the *bottom*, before it goes under/over the footer. Any ideas on how to make that moving red box stop right above the green footer? The height of the footer is 1000px, so I'd somehow need to set the moving box to stop at 1000px from the bottom.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
(function(jQuery) {
    var element = jQuery('.move'),
        originalY = element.offset().top;

    var topMargin = 110;

    element.css('position', 'relative');

    jQuery(window).on('scroll', function(event) {
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

        element.stop(false, false).animate({
            top: scrollTop < originalY
                    ? 0
                    : scrollTop - originalY + topMargin
        }, 200);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: do you try var topMargin = 300; ??

Answer (score 0):

I modified following line by adding static value 290 and it reached to bottom.

scrollTop - originalY + topMargin + 290

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you trying to achive?

```
(function(jQuery) {
   var element = $('.move'),
   originalY = element.offset().top, 
   otherDiv = 1000,
   staticHeight = $('.other-div').height()-$(element).height(); // Fixed number to stop the move-element                        before the footer

   var topMargin = 110;

   jQuery(window).on('scroll', function(event) { 
      var offset = element.offset().top; 
      var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

      // Check if the move-block gets under the footerblock
      if(scrollTop < otherDiv){ 
          element.stop(false, false).animate({
              top: scrollTop - originalY + topMargin
          }, 200);
      }else{
        element.stop(false, false).animate({
          top: staticHeight //If so, make sure it gets on top of the footerblock staticly
        }, 200);
      }
   });
})(jQuery);
```

I think you need an if/else statement to check if the block gets behind the height of the div called "other-div".

See the working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/crix/z578c9bo/

Hope it helps!